# why am I getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'company') even if component renders correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, async-pipe

I'm trying to get some company data from an api into this component in this way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-company-details',
  templateUrl: './company-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-details.component.css']
})
export class CompanyDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() companyId!: number
  company! : CompanyInterface
  subscription! : Subscription
  constructor(private companiesService : CompaniesService) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.companiesService.getCompanyDetails(this.companyId)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.company = response
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

what I'm doing here is taking the companyId as Input from the parent component and then using that to get the data trough my CompaniesService and then I'm displaying the data into the component's HTML template like this:

```
<article class="company-details">
  <h4>COMPANY DETAILS</h4>
  <div class="company-description">
    <h5>DESCRIPTION</h5>
    <p>{{company.description}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="company-locations">
    <h5>LOCATIONS</h5>
    <p>We are in:
      <span *ngFor="let location of company.locations">{{location.name}},</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="company-size">
    <span><h5>SIZE: {{company.size.short_name | uppercase}}</h5> </span>
  </div>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</article>
```

everything works fine and the data renders correctly but in the console I get this error:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'company')`

what am I doing wrongg here? does this have something to do with components lifecycle?

Comment: Because despite telling TypeScript that the property is never undefined (`company!`), it *is* undefined until the subscription completes (and the `response` is defined). You should not use the exclamation point unless you know for a fact that the value is never undefined, or it leads to bugs like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ? in TypeScript. Update this line and it should be fine.

```
<span *ngFor="let location of company?.locations">{{location.name}},</span>
```

Also you can make this much cleaner solution with using **async** pipe.

```
// In your component typescript file
company$ : CompanyInterface

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.company$ = this.companiesService.getCompanyDetails(this.companyId);
 }

// In HTML
<span *ngFor="let location of company$ | async">{{location?.name}},</span>
```

In this case you would avoid subscribe and unsubscribe.

Comment: thanks for answering, is this the most "elegant" way to do it in your opinion?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check it out.